# Differential equation with one univariate function and several variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, functional-equations

I have a functional equation where I need to find *one univariate* function which satisfies conditions involving two variables, for example, find a function $f$ which satisfies, for all $x,y$:

$$
x (x+y) f'(x)(f(y)-f(x)) = (x-y)(f(x)-f^2(x))
$$

How are such equations called? I would like to find literature, but I don't even know where to begin, and what terms to use. This is not an ODE, but also not a PDE.

Comment: What do you mean ``one univariate function which satisfies conditions dictated by two variables''?

Comment: I gave an example in the post. I need to find a univariate function $f$, but the condition it should satisfy involves two separate independent variables $x,y$ which should be satisfied for all $x,y$ in its domain.

Comment: I saw the example you gave, but what you say in your post does not make sense. From your comment I understand that $x$ and $y$ are not two variables, they are two different values of the same variable. Maybe you could edit your post to make this clear.

Comment: It depends on your definition of a 'variable'. They are two different arguments of the function $f$.

Comment: The terms variable and argument already have precise definitions, which are not subject to personal interpretation.

Comment: Well, if you must go there, then the condition should be satisfied for all $x,y$, and in mathematical logic in the context of "for all $x,y$" the symbols $x$ and $y$ are called _variables_, and the condition is called a predicate. So they _are_ variables, depending on the context. But that doesn't matter. What matters is that I want to be able to solve such functional equations, and I need a mathematical term to call them :)

Comment: Does $f^2(x)$ mean $(f(x))^2$ in this context?

Comment: @Rollen Yes, but the question is not about this specific equation. It's about what is the correct term to describe such a kind of equations, so that I can find information about solving them.

Comment: Such equations are called [*functional differential equations (FDEs)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation). Functional equations are generally difficault to solve, as you may know. The situation is even worse for FDEs. Only for certain simple classes of equations there are general methods, as you can see in the link. Like functional equations, you usually need to treat an FDE in a different manner than the other FDEs. The Wikipedia page is in fact about a certain sort of FDEs, and the term "FDE" is usually used in a more general sense, which includes your example.

Comment: On second thought, I think I was wrong about the Wikipedia page being about a special case of FDEs. The definition given At the beginning is in fact what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is (as stated in the comments) that the proper term is "[functional differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation)".  However, I would caution you about making a full frontal assault on your problem via the methods associated with FDE's.  There are many problems which can be phrased as FDE's, but trying to solve them via general FDE techniques is often very ineffective.

A somewhat general "meta-technique" for solving hard problems involving derivatives$^1$ is to reduce the problem by

1. Finding a necessary (but perhaps not sufficient) ODE that your solution must solve.
2. Determining the solution space of the ODE.
3. Looking within the solution space of the ODE for the solution to your original problem.

You can apply this technique to your example problem as follows: Set $y=x+\epsilon$ and take $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ to find a related ODE $$2x^2 f'(x)^2 = f(x)^2-f(x)$$ which your unknown function $f$ must solve.  This ODE is separable and can be solved analytically!  It is first order, so there is a 1-parameter solution space.  Check through the solution space to determine which solutions satisfy the original equation involving $x$ and $y$, and then you're done.

So you can see how this line of reasoning can substantially constrain your possible solutions.  I would advise trying to make reductions like this before wandering through FDE land too much.

---

*1. For example, the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) and the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) can be thought of this way.*